# How to create join logical file in as400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am having one Physical file which contains even numbers(2,4,6,8,10) and another PF which contains odd numbers(1,3,5,7,9). Is that we can create join logical file, which I have to use in RPGLE pgm to display numbers in sequence from(1 to 10).

How can I create join logical file for this scenario?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No need to create another file. Just read a record of data consecutively from each existing file, one file after the other, in a loop until end-of-file. As already noted in two Answers, the problem appears to want a solution that requires using a UNION of the two data sets rather than a JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

FWiW, an example of using a UNION VIEW in the *same* capacity as, but instead of a[n implicitly] Multi-Format Logical File (MFLF) which are not considered "relational" by the database:

Setup:

```
create table even_nbrs
( nbr     dec     not null with default
, nbrtext char(2) not null with default
)
;
create table odd_nbrs
( nbr     dec     not null with default
, nbrtext char(2) not null with default
)
;
insert into  even_nbrs values      
(2, 2), (4, 4), (6, 6), (8, 8), (10, 10)
; -- 5 rows inserted in EVEN_NBRS
insert into  odd_nbrs  values           
(1, 1), (3, 3), (5, 5), (7, 7), ( 9,  9)
; -- 5 rows inserted in ODD_NBRS
```

Create the file producing the UNION of data records from the prior two files:

```
create view  evens_odds as      
( select nbr, nbrtext from even_nbrs
 union all                          
  select nbr, nbrtext from odd_nbrs 
)
;
```

Make the VIEW available to the RPG program as a shared Open Data Path (ODP) for which the order is by the *numbered\sequence* (NBR) column, use for the run-time CL processing:

```
ovrdbf     the_File tofile(evens_odds) mbr(*first) share(*yes)    
opnqryf    the_File keyfld((nbr))
/* optionally, the next three commands to test and review results: */
cpyfrmqryf the_File *print
dspsplf    qsysprt splnbr(*last)
posdbf     the_File *start
/* call the RPG program that could read by key or sequentially */
call       the_RPGpgm
```

And, for the [*non-relational*] DDS LF, the MFLF would have the following DDS:

```
                R ODDS_EVENS                PFILE(ODD_NBRS EVEN_NBRS)
                  NBR                                                
                  NBRTEXT                                            
                K NBR
```

After the Create Logical File (CRTLF) using that DDS source to create a file named ODDS_EVENS, the following CL requests can verify the results:

```
cpyf ODDS_EVENS *print fromrcd(*start)
dspsplf qsysprt splnbr(*last)
```

**[edit:18May2015]**

The following DDS LF source is an explicitly defined MFLF, but the *first format* [the first R-spec] is duplicated [i.e. the second format seen in DSPFD TYPE(*RCDFMT) after the CRTLF is a duplicate of the first] and effects a UNION of the data in the two files specified on the PFILE(). Whereas the third and fourth formats [the 2nd and 3rd R-spec] are explicitly defined and clearly distinct from the first; the differences between the third and fourth and the differences between each and the first, should be seen as conspicuously dissimilar, so as to indicate they are not a UNION and instead effectively distinct logical views of various data encapsulated in a single *FILE object.

The simplest interface to see the data [though not necessarily reflecting the order] is using the Query/400 interactive WRKQRY feature to select the different Formats in the Specify File Selections and after each successive selection to use the F5=Run feature. Either the Select And Sequence Fields of that utility, or just Display File Field Descriptions (DSPFFD) to see the layout of each format.

This example does not attempt to perform anything useful, merely tries to emphasize the union and the multiple-formats generated for that union, and show how the other multiple-formats are explicitly coded as diverse VIEW-like entities. 
Also, unless the following SQL statement is run [following the setup from the prior file\data setup activity], the reference to the data in RcdFmt(ODDS_ONLY) would result in decimal data mapping errors due to the blanks for the single-digit values originally input as character values [mapped from integer values]: `update odd_nbrs set nbrtext = right(digits(nbr), 2)`

```
                R ODDS_EVENS                PFILE(ODD_NBRS EVEN_NBRS)           
                                            TEXT('NBR fld only; 1-digit values')
                  NBR  
                K NBR  
                K *NONE
                K *NONE
                S NBR                       COMP(LT 10)    
                R ODDS_ONLY                 PFILE(ODD_NBRS)
                                            TEXT('NBR,NBRTEXT mapped to zoned')
                  NBR                
                  NBRTEXT        2S00
                K NBR    
                K NBRTEXT
                K *NONE
                R EVENS_ONLY                PFILE(EVEN_NBRS)                    
                                            TEXT('NBR to alpha and more zoned')
                  NBR
                  NBR2S00        2S00       RENAME(NBR) COLHDG('NBR2S00')
                  NBR2A          2A  I      SST(NBR2S00 1 2) COLHDG('NBR2A')
                  NBRTEXT
                K *NONE  
                K *NONE  
                K NBR2S00
```

**[/edit:18May2015]**

Answer (score 1):

You are not describing a join logical, which joins a record from one table to one or more records in another table.

Instead, you are describing what is known as a [multi-format logical](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakb/simpmult.htm) the DDS source for which would look like so (assuming the record formats between the files are the same):

```
A          R RECFMT                    PFILE(ODDFILE EVENFILE)
A            RECNO
A            FLD1
A            FLD2
A          K RECNO
```

If however, the two files have different record formats, and you want different fields from each...then it'd look something like so:

```
A          R ODDFILER                  PFILE(ODDFILE)
A            RECNO
A            FLD1
A            FLD3
A          K RECNO
A 
A          R EVENFILER                 PFILE(EVENFILE)
A            RECNO
A            FLD2
A            FLD4
A          K RECNO
```

Here's a decent article about using join and multi-format logicals.
http://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/general/multi-format-and-join-logicals.html

As CRPence's answer mentions, a MFLF is similar to an SQL UNION ALL view.

The difference is that a MFLF would allow for in my second example, FLD1 to be alpha and FLD2 to be numeric.  An SQL union view will not allow that; the columns selected in an SQL must be of same (or compatible) types.

Comment: The proper way to create the described files is to use the implicitly multi-format logical file (MFLF) specifying just one record format name and multiple file names in the one `PFILE()` specification; i.e. `PFILE(ODDFILE EVENFILE)`

Comment: @CRPence...good catch.  Didn't realize you could do that...everytime I've seen/used a MFLF it's been with different formats.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The multiple-file specification on the PFILE creates an effective UNION of the data in the included members under than named format; and implicitly, the file appears to be a MFLF, but all of the *Record Formats* are identical (name and all). That is somewhat contrary to the typical MFLF, which indeed are typically just different layouts [including mappings] and\or selection [and similarly keyed sometimes using K *NONE], but they do not effect a UNION; they effective provide different VIEWs of the file.mbrs to which each refers. Maybe I should read that article to see what it's about ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Think of each physical file as a grid or table where the records in your file are rows, and the fields in your file are the columns. (These are also the terms used in SQL.)  Imagine putting the two tables side by side. A join will connext & combine rows together where the keys match, to build new result rows each containing values from both tables.

But that's not the scenario you have described at all.  You want to have the two tables combined vertically, more like taking two piles of cards and sorting them together into one pile, in the desired sequence.